# NVIDIA graphics driver correctly installed, still ubuntu-drivers doesn't detect any video device

Tags: 19.10, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-geforce, ubuntu-drivers, nvidia-prime

My Ubuntu 19.10 laptop has hybrid Intel/NVidia graphics, and the latter is of the Fermi legacy kind; I managed to install `nvidia-driver-390` as suggested and troubleshooted [in this post on the nvidia developer forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-19-10-card-geforce-820m-no-response-by-both-nvidia-smi-and-ubuntu-drivers/117969). Still, `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` nor the "Additional Drivers" section in Software & Updates detects any video driver to choose from. Still, the driver is correctly detected by other means

```
~$lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09) 04:00.0 
3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)

~$nvidia-smi
Fri Apr  3 15:21:30 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.132                Driver Version: 390.132                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 820M        Off  | 00000000:04:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   40C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    476MiB /  1985MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

~$dkms status
nvidia, 390.132, 5.3.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 390.132, 5.3.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed

~$mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

~$grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | grep graphics-drivers
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-eoan.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu eoan main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-eoan.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu eoan main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-eoan.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu eoan main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-eoan.list.save:# deb-src http://
```

ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu eoan main

p://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu eoan main

How should I proceed? Thank you in advance.

P.S.: how the `nvidia-driver-390` driver was installed

1. Added `graphics-drivers` repository with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
2. Disabled Secure Boot, both from the BIOS and with `sudo mokutil --disable-validation`
3. `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390`
4. Removed `/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf`, there was no `/etc/*` counterpart
5. Uncommented `#WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
6. Removed `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, under forum suggestion.
7. Reboot

Optionally, just to have vsync work, I set `1` in option `options nvidia-drm modeset=1` of `/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-kms.conf`

**UPDATE: Filed as a bug** with `ubuntu-bug ubuntu-drivers-common`

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1870821

Comment: Have you disabled the Secure Boot in the BIOS?

Comment: Sorry, yes I have. I will update the question accordingly

Comment: How did you install the driver?  Did you download it from NVIDIA or did you get it from setting up the `graphics-drivers` ppa?  Which the latter is actually the recommended way to install the drivers for NVIDIA cards.

Comment: @Terrance from the ppa, as in the final section of the question

Comment: You didn't add any information about adding in the graphics-drivers ppa like  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`  If you did do it that way and it is still failing to show your NVIDIA hardware, file it as a bug for the `ubuntu-drivers`.  Run it as `ubuntu-bug ubuntu-drivers`

Comment: @Terrance Sorry for the misunderstanding yes I added the ppa graphics drivers beforehand, will update question

Comment: It honestly sounds like it's a bug and should be filed as one.  Your configuration is correct and it should be working.  The only other way to confirm that it is a bug is to actually install another version like 18.04 LTS and see if it follows.  From my experience though, this really sounds like a bug in the `ubuntu-drivers` app.

Comment: @Terrance filed as a bug, thank you meanwhile